# How to install DisplayLink driver in Xubuntu 21.10 Impish Indri

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, displaylink

This is the [DisplayLink driver](https://www.synaptics.com/node/4151?filetype=exe) downloaded and extracted in my computer.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7hd2.png

I'd like to install by following [this instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisplayLink) .

But I could not install.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZptY.png

```
root@office002:/home/office002# cd Downloads/displaylinkdriver550beta59118
root@office002:/home/office002/Downloads/displaylinkdriver550beta59118# sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.5.0-beta-59.118.run
sudo: ./displaylink-driver-5.5.0-beta-59.118.run: command not found
root@office002:/home/office002/Downloads/displaylinkdriver550beta59118#
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Why are you uploading pictures of text and pictures of your file manager? We can't work with information presented this way. It's not clear what you are trying to do, nor is it clear what problems you are experiencing. Please edit your question and include more details. All text should be copy/pasted into your question so we can work with it. If you obtained files or drivers from some place, please link to the page that hosts these files and describe where you obtained them and why you think you need them.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the file executable.

`chmod +x displaylink-driver-5.5.0-beta-59.118.run`

Than run it

`sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.5.0-beta-59.118.run`

Comment: After installing the driver, [Xubuntu boots normally.](https://imgur.com/PXhBMTr.png)
But there is [an error message](https://imgur.com/VBNJ7RE.png):
`/dev/sda5: clean, 254758/14426112 files, 4620549/57686528 blocks
{FAILED} Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.`

Anyway, Xubuntu can work after this error message disappears.
What was wrong with the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Any results on this? I installed the DisplyLink driver but still gert nothing.
I have Wacom DTU-1031x/k that doesn't seem to recognize the displatlink screen under Zorin OS, an Ubuntu variant, or Mac OS 10.13.xx.

The drawing tablet part works under Linux, but bo screen no matter what.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1233066)